# Changing instance variables from a method in a class

Tags: python, instance-variables

I've made a class with some variables being set in the ___init____ and I want to be able to change these variables from methods in that class ie.

```
class example_class:

    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.thing = 'variable'

    def example_method(self):
        self.thing = 'changed text'

    def different_method(self):
        print(self.thing)
```

So before calling "example_method" the value of self.thing is the string 'variable' and then after calling the method "example_method" self.thing now equals 'changed text'. This must be possible but I don't understand how to do it

Comment: What problem are you actually seeing with your implementation?

Comment: After running the method example_method the value of self.thing is still the original string 'variable' it hasn't changed to 'changed text'

Answer (score 1):

You must call the method you've defined into the class to happen.

```
class example_class:

    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.thing = 'variable'
        self.example_method()

    def example_method(self):
        self.thing = 'changed text'

    def different_method(self):
```

In this way, when you get/create an instance of the class "example_class", the method "example_method" will be called in the constructor.

You could also do something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class = example_class()
    my_class.example_method()
```

Comment: I realise I haven't but the code in my post but I do call the method I just don't want to call it in the init. I want to construct the instance of the class and then later be able to call "example_method" to change the variable self.thing

Comment: you don't need to call the method inside the __init__ method if you won't. But as i said in my previous post, you want something similar to the last 3 rows of code. You need an instance of that class and after you can easily call the method you want from it.

Comment: Yeah I have created an instance of the class and then call the method but the string still doesn't change

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, please post the code.